# Rotation Vector sensor keeps reporting high accuracy even when clearly wrong

Tags: android, kotlin, android-sensors

I'm using a rotation vector sensor like this:

```
val sensor = sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(TYPE_ROTATION_VECTOR)
```

I register a `SensorEventListener` on it:

```
private class OrientationListener : SensorEventListener {
    private val rotationMatrix = FloatArray(9)

    override fun onSensorChanged(event: SensorEvent) {
        if (event.sensor.type != TYPE_ROTATION_VECTOR) return
        SensorManager.getRotationMatrixFromVector(rotationMatrix, event.values)
        val easting = rotationMatrix[0]
        val northing = rotationMatrix[3]
        val azimuth = -atan2(northing, easting)
        val azimuthAccuracy = event.accuracy
            debug { "Azimuth changed to ${azimuth}, accuracy ${azimuthAccuracy}" }
        }
    }

    override fun onAccuracyChanged(sensor: Sensor, accuracy: Int) {
        if (sensor.type == TYPE_ROTATION_VECTOR) {
            info { "Azimuth accuracy changed to $accuracy" }
        }
    }
}
```

I have never observed this code report anything but `SENSOR_STATUS_ACCURACY_HIGH`, even at times when it was obviously wrong (inside the car, for example). Yet Google Maps and other applications show low accuracy in these situations.

What are these other apps using to find out the actual accuracy of the compass orientation?